# how to parse list of values to a command using a for sentence?

Tags: for-loop

my question is do you have any idea how to parse a list of arguments as a variable in for statement

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 192.168.1.11 | awk -F ":" 'NF{print $NF}' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'

vbox
vbox2
vbox3
vbox4
vbox5
vbox6
```

i want to pass a single parameter (vbox, vbox2,vbox3...) to a iscsi command to discover and login to this truenas vm

```
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox -p 192.168.1.11 -l
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox2 -p 192.168.1.11 -l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u mean like this ?

```
echo 'vbox vbox2 vbox3 vbox4 vbox5 vbox6' |
```

> ```
>  mawk 'sub(".+","iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas." \
>            "ctl:& -p 192.168.1.11 -l")^_' ORS=' ' RS='[[:space:]]+'
> ```

```
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox -p 192.168.1.11 -l iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox2 -p 192.168.1.11 -l iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox3 -p 192.168.1.11 -l iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox4 -p 192.168.1.11 -l iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox5 -p 192.168.1.11 -l iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:vbox6 -p 192.168.1.11 -l
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks RARE Kpop Manifesto !!!

also i have this one

printf '%s\n' "${nas[@]}" |paste -sd ' '

for nas in $vbox; do
discover=`iscsiadm -m node -T $connector:$nas -p $ip -l`
done